# Access to Nested Json objects in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, json

I have a json object as a response from the server . I want to acces to `Base64Signature` object , i don't know how because some objects names are not accessible such as `@WhichDocument` and `sc.ExtendedSignatureObject` . This is the response from the server

```
   { 'sc.SignatureObjects':
   { 'sc.ExtendedSignatureObject': { '@WhichDocument': 'AISDoc1', Base64Signature: [Object] } } }
```

Comment: use bracket notation property accessors ```myData['sc.SignatureObjects']['sc.ExtendedSignatureObject']['Base64Signature']);```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access it like this with [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors):

```js
let data = { 'sc.SignatureObjects':
   { 'sc.ExtendedSignatureObject': { '@WhichDocument': 'AISDoc1', Base64Signature: {obj: 'data'} } } }
   
   
console.log(data['sc.SignatureObjects']['sc.ExtendedSignatureObject'].Base64Signature)
```